# edit margin of only the image which is surrounded by text: html / css

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

Okay so I have text with an image inside it, like so

```
<h1>First<img alt="image" src="../images/middle.png">Name</h1>
```

and now, I dont want the text to be in the center of the image (I know I can do it by adding vertical-align to the image) but I want the text to be about 3.5/4 of the Image, so not exactly in the middle of the image, but a bit to the bottom of the image. I decided to try adding a  margin-top to the image but then that moved the image and the h1 down as well. I then tried

```
<h1 class="text">First</h1><img alt="image" src"../images/middle.png"><h1 class="text">Name</h1>
```

This made the first h1, the image and the second h1 appear all on different lines. I then tried making the h1 displays inline but then I can back to the first problem, when I made a margin-top on the image, the h1's will drop down as well along with the image.

So, any idea on how to make the image which is inside of the lines of text change it's vertical position while not changing the vertical position of the text around the image?

Comment: Can I see the CSS you have used so far?

Comment: I was playing around and changing up my CSS, trying everything from margin-top's to display: inline's to vertical-align's and then RwwL's answered showed that I can vertical-align using pixels (and even negative pixels) and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried *all* the different values of CSS vertical align (baseline, text-top, text-bottom, etc.) to see if one gets what you want?

If not, try them all — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align — and try them in different combinations with line-height values set on your h1 element.

Comment: Ah, perfect, vertical-align: -16px worked perfectly. It's great how we can define the vertical-align by pixels, and even go in the negative values. That's extremely convenient. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! If this is for a CMS template of some sort, just make sure the negative vertical align won't bite you depending on the words in the element. I think letters with descenders *might* get cut off when you use that.

Comment: oh man, good point. And yes it is for a template. Okay for now i'm going to continue using the negative alignment but I need to find a better solution :/

Comment: I messed around in CodePen after writing this and now I actually think you're OK; I don't think you'll have that cut-off descenders issue that I was concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

this is a case where you want to use absolute positioning for the `<h1>` text, otherwise you can't have 2 `<h1>` tags on the same line - as you already found out, try something like

```
<h1 class="text" class="txt1">First</h1><img alt="image" src"../images/middle.png"><h1 class="txt2">Name</h1>

.txt1{
     position:absolute;
     top:15px;
}
.txt2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

obviously I have no idea how big your "middle.png" is, so adjust top and left numbers accordingly

Comment: Right, this solution works as well, I just didn't want to go into absolute positioning but yea this would've been what I would have had to resort to. The solution above is great as well.